# Questions while using Apache Curator in service registration and discovery

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

1. I'm using `ServiceDiscovery.registerService()` to register a service to zookeeper server, should I call ServiceDiscovery's `close()` method right after I register a service?
2. In Curator's documentation it suggests reusing ServiceProvider objects, should I reuse ServiceDiscovery objects too?
   The Curator version is 2.8.0, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(note: I'm the main author of Curator)

No you should not call `close()` after registering. Close is to be used when your application is shutting down. It closes all caches, unregisters services, etc.

You only need 1 ServiceDiscovery instance per application.